# WCF Server handling missing Content-Type

Tags: .net, wcf, http

I have a WCF server that handles a POST command. I created the endpoint with the WebHttpBinding.
My problem is that I have no control over the client that sends the POST. As it turns out the client does not send the Content-Type.
Is there a way for me to handle this? I know what the content type should be. Is it possible to intercept the request and add the content type?

Comment: You can use the IDispatchMessageInspector interfaces AfterRecieveRequest method to handle the request and perform the necessary operations. reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.afterreceiverequest.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IDisptachMessageInspector interfaces AfterRecieveRequest method to handle the request and perform the necessary operations

[IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.afterreceiverequest.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't help. The server rejects the request before it gets to my AfterReceiveRequest method. I can tell that the inspector is set up OK because it is reached when the content-type field is sent.